# Qt: how to pass input values from on_pushButton_clicked() function to paintGL()

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a mortgage calculator with QT.
When the user clicks the push button, the "on_pushButton_clicked()" function will get the inputs.

The Question is I am confused about how to pass the inputs from "on_pushButton_clicked()" to "paintGL()" function for drawing purpose.

My last resort is using global variables to solve this issue, but I really want to avoid something like that...so it will be more than welcome if someone can enlighten with better approaches.

My code are as followed:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    template <class T>
    T inputcheck(QLineEdit *input, T output);
    //friend class GLwidget;
    double loan;
    int maturity;
    double rate1;
    double rate2;
    double rate3;
    int period2;
    int period3;    

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_Quit_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include "glwidget.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

template <class T>
T MainWindow::inputcheck(QLineEdit *input, T output) 
{
    bool ok;
    output = input->text().toDouble(&ok);
    if(TRUE && output > 0)
    {
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        input->setText("ERR");
        return 0;
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{

    // getting inputs()
    loan = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    maturity = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    rate1 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate1, rate1);
    rate2 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate2, rate2);
    rate3 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate3, rate3);
    period2 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_period2, period2);
    period3 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_period3, period3);
    printf("loan:%f, maturity:%d,rate1:%f,rate2:%f,rate3:%f, period2:%d, period3:%d\n", loan, maturity, rate1, rate2, rate3, period2, period3);      

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Quit_clicked()
{
    QCoreApplication::quit();

}
```

glwidget.h

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QGLWidget>


class calculation;
class GLwidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLwidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);

private:

};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

glwidget.cpp

```
#include "glwidget.h"
#include <gl/GL.h>


GLwidget::GLwidget(QWidget *parent):QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void GLwidget::initializeGL()
{
}

void GLwidget::paintGL()
{
**// I need the inputs to be here!!**
}

void GLwidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
}
```

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: You're missing the code for `main`. And how is the `MainWindow` made aware of a `GLwidget`'s existence? Finally, you should be using `QOpenGLWidget` as it's a more modern API and interoperates better with other widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic approach is to make the widget become a display for the values, with the values being the properties for the widget. This is how all Qt controls work, e.g. a `QLabel` can display some text, and has a `text` property that you set using `setText`. Once `setText` is called with a new text, the label knows to update itself. Thus:

```
class DataView : public QOpenGLWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(double principal READ principal WRITE setPrincipal)
  Q_PROPERTY(int amortizationPeriod READ amortizationPeriod WRITE setAmortizationPeriod)
  ...
  double m_principal = {};
  int m_amortizationPeriod = {};
public:
  explicit GLwidget(QWidget *parent = {}) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) {}
  void initializeGL() override;
  void paintGL() override;
  void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
  double principal() const { return m_principal; }
  void setPrincipal(double principal) {
    if (m_principal == principal) return;
    m_principal = principal;
    update();
  }
  int amortizationPeriod() const { return m_amortizationPeriod; }
  void setAmortizationPeriod(int period) {
    if (m_amortizationPeriod == period) return;
    m_amortizationPeriod = period;
    update();
  }
  ...
};
```

`update()` schedules a repaint from the event loop. The update requests are coalesced, thus setting multiple properties in a row only paints the widget once.

Thus, assuming that you hold the `dataView` as an element of the Ui form:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    auto principal = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    auto amortizationPeriod = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    ...
    ui->dataView->setPrincipal(principal);
    ui->dataView->setAmortizationPeriod(amortizationPeriod);
    ...
}
```

Perhaps you're wishing to show the `dataView` dynamically as a new top-level window:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    auto principal = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    auto amortizationPeriod = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    ...
    auto dataView = new DataView(this);
    dataView->setWindowFlags(dataWidget->windowFlags() | Qt::Window);
    dataView->setPrincipal(principal);
    dataView->setAmortizationPeriod(amortizationPeriod);
    ...
    dataView->show();
}
```

If you wish to make it easier to pass data around, you can bundle all of the properties in a data type representing a loan:

```
struct Loan {
  double principal = {};
  int amortizationPeriod = {};
  ...
  bool operator==(const Loan & o) const {
    return 
      qFuzzyCompare(principal, o.principal)
      && amortizationPeriod == o.amortizationPeriod
      && ...;
    // use qFuzzyCompare when comparing floating point values
  }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Loan)

class DataView : public QOpenGLWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(Loan loan READ loan WRITE setLoan)
  Loan m_loan;
public:
  explicit GLwidget(QWidget *parent = {}) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) {}
  void initializeGL() override;
  void paintGL() override;
  void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
  const Loan & loan() const { return m_loan; }
  Loan getLoan() const { return m_loan; }
  void setLoan(const Loan & loan) {
     if (m_loan == loan) return;
     m_loan = loan;
     update();
  }
};
```

When convenient, one can use `getLoan` to get a modifiable copy of the loan. The usual `loan` getter has low cost since it returns a const reference to the internal data, not a copy.

Then:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    Loan loan;
    loan.principal = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    loan.amortizationPeriod = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    ...
    ui->dataView->setLoan(loan);
    ...
}
```

If you're wishing to show the `dataView` dynamically as a new top-level window:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    Loan loan;
    loan.principal = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    loan.amortizationPeriod = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    ...
    auto dataView = new DataView(this);
    dataView->setWindowFlags(dataView->windowFlags() | Qt::Window);
    dataView->setLoan(loan);
    dataView->show();
}
```

You can also decouple the data view from the `MainWindow` completely and pass the data out via a signal:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  ...
public:
  Q_SLOT newLoan(const Loan &);
  ...
};

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    Loan loan;
    loan.principal = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    loan.amortizationPeriod = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    ...
    emit newLoan(loan);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow mainWindow;
  DataView dataView;
  QObject::connect(&mainWindow, &MainWindow::newLoan, [&](const Loan & loan){
    dataView.setLoan(loan);
    dataView.show();
  });
  mainWindow.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

If the data view is always visible, you'd have:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow mainWindow;
  DataView dataView;
  QObject::connect(&mainWindow, &MainWindow::newLoan, &dataView, &DataView::setLoan);
  mainWindow.show();
  dataView.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate paragraphs 'Perhaps you're wishing to show the dataView dynamically as a new top-level window' and no this is not what is asked. I personnaly prefer short, simple and coherent answers...

Comment: @Tezirg There are no duplicate paragraphs. Given the open-ended nature of the question, I had no choice but to show several possible implementations depending on what the asker desires. If you look at the code you'll see that it's not identical across paragraphs. Anything short of the above makes unwarranted assumptions about the structure of the user code, and I'm not sure I've not missed a yet another viable scenario.

Comment: @KubaOber: Thanks for your help! I really need sometime to process though. I just started using Qt lately. Btw, is there any recommended tutorial for QOpenGLWidget?

Comment: Qt comes with many megabytes of examples. Understand them and you'll be well on your way to using QOpenGLWidget well.

Answer (score 0):

Move the variables in your GLwidget class. Here I assumed they are declared public, but you might want to use setters and getters. Then, call update to refresh the widget.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked()
{
    ui->myglwidgetname->loan = inputcheck<double>(ui->lineEdit_loan);
    ui->myglwidgetname->maturity = inputcheck<int>(ui->lineEdit_maturity);
    ui->myglwidgetname->rate1 = inputcheck<double>(ui->lineEdit_rate1);
    ui->myglwidgetname->rate2 = inputcheck<double>(ui->lineEdit_rate2);
    ui->myglwidgetname->rate3 = inputcheck<double>(ui->lineEdit_rate3);
    ui->myglwidgetname->period2 = inputcheck<int>(ui->lineEdit_period2);
    ui->myglwidgetname->period3 = inputcheck<int>(ui->lineEdit_period3);
    ui->myglwidgetname->update();    
}
```

Additionaly, you want to correct your templated function because it is calling `toDouble` regardless of the type T which doesn't make sense at all...

Comment: Generally speaking, having a widget's users invoke `update()` is an API bug since the implementation detail of a widget leaks out. E.g. after you `setText` on a `QLabel`, you shouldn't need to worry about such details. A widget's user should never need to invoke `update`. Essentially, that method should have been protected - it's an omission in Qt's API design. Instead, use setter methods that automatically schedule an update when a value has changed.

Comment: @Tezirg: Definitely, but I am still trying to figure out how to do that according to the input type. I just started using Qt lately and I dont know if there is any solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved by using some common object oriented ideas, namely member variables with setter functions. In your subclass of the QGLWidget (glwidget.h) add some member variables.

```
private:
  int m_my_int_value;
  double m_my_double_value;
```

You will then also want some setter functions for those values (also in glwidget.h).

```
public:
  void Set_my_int_value(int val);
  void Set_my_double_value(double val);
```

You can the put the declarations for those functions in glwidget.cpp.

```
void GLwidget::Set_my_int_value(int val)
{
  if(val != m_my_int_value)
  {
    m_my_int_value = val;
    update();
  }
}

void GLwidget::Set_my_double_value(double val)
{
  if(val != m_my_double_value)
  {
    m_my_double_value = val;
    update();
  }
}
```

Call those setter functions in your on_click function. Those values will then be accessible in your implementation of paintGL.

Comment: The setters must call `update()` to schedule a repaint of the widget, and should also do nothing when the value doesn't change.

Comment: @Chris: Thank you for helping me out. Could you please clarify where I should put the setter functions?

Comment: The setters and the member variables all should be in glwidget.h. If the setters need to do something more complicated you can put the definition for them in glwidget.cpp

Answer (score -1):

You can use qt's Signal/Slot mechanizm for it.

Create your own struct, with the needed fields from the input. You can pass it as a pointer through a signal.

Add to mainwindow.h

```
signals:
    void MySignal(MyStruct*);
```

in the cpp:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_Calculate_clicked(){

// getting inputs()
    loan = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_loan, loan);
    maturity = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_maturity, maturity);
    rate1 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate1, rate1);
    rate2 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate2, rate2);
    rate3 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_rate3, rate3);
    period2 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_period2, period2);
    period3 = inputcheck(ui->lineEdit_period3, period3);
    printf("loan:%f, maturity:%d,rate1:%f,rate2:%f,rate3:%f, period2:%d, period3:%d\n", loan, maturity, rate1, rate2, rate3, period2, period3); 
    MyStruct* struct = new MyStruct();
    ... //add data to mystruct
    emit MySignal(struct);
}
```

have a function like this:
    public slots:
        void saveData(MyStruct* param); //body should saves the data however you like it

And in possibly main.cpp, where you create the two main widget, have something like this.

```
MainWindow mainW();
GLWidget glW();
connect(&mainW, SIGNAL( MySignal(MyStruct*)), &glW, SLOT(saveData(MyStruct*)));
```

It is a little rough around the edges, but i hope you get the basic idea. If not, check Qt documentation on Signal/Slot mechanizm.

Comment: Passing the data structure around as a raw pointer cannot be done safely and is a bug. The signal/slot mechanism is used to decouple the code. The emitter of a signal cannot assume anything about the slots nor connection types. By the time the slot is invoked, the pointer might be dangling, or the data might be in the process of being changed, leading to undefined behavior. Instead, pass `MyStruct` by const reference. Qt will then be able to copy it when needed: `Q_SIGNAL void newStruct(const MyStruct &);` and `struct MyStruct { ... }; Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyStruct)`.

Comment: @Hajdu: Thanks for the tips! I am a newcomer for Qt so not very familiar with those features, but I will sure try it!